# std::filesystem::is_regular_file() vs ::exists()- what counts as a regular file

Tags: c++, mfc, filesystems, file-exists

I am using Visual Studio 2017 C++ **WITH MFC**

---

I have a program in MFC that collects filepaths as `string`s and adds them to a `zip` file.

I want to add an error check, where I check if a file exists before trying to add it. If it exists, perfect, I add the file to the `zip`. If not, not a problem, I continue to the next filepath.

I came across `std::filesystem` ([here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)) and I see two different functions that I think can work:
`is_regular_file()` ([here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file)) and `exists()` ([here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists)).

However, I am not sure which of the two to use. The file types I will be `zipping` vary from `.txt` to `.zip`, and a lot of arbitrary file types.

From my research, they appear to be similar, both returning a `bool` value.

What is the difference between the two functions and which is the better one to use?

Furthermore, from my understanding, the library is relatively new and might not be suitable for use in `MFC`. Is this true? And if so, what else could I use to check if given a file path, that file exists on the computer?

Thank you in advance ! :D

Comment: I think the example code for `is_regular_file()` kinda says it all. I would think that `exists()` is what you want.

Comment: While not an answer to your explicit question - I would recommend attempting to add every file and handling errors as they come.  File systems can always change outside of the control of your program, so the result of `std::filesystem::exists` (whether true or false) can never guarantee that you _will_ or _will not_ be able to open the file.

Comment: @jkb what do you mean by that ? to me the two examples are somewhat inadequate and I cannot tell them apart

Comment: @DrewDormann  I agree that would be ideal, however, the library I am using to zip was not made by me, and I would like to avoid the error at all; I am also assuming the user will not be going around the computer deleting files as the zipping is on progress

Comment: There are several types of files, particularly in the *nix environments. The example code checks for each type of file that `filesystem` can detect. One of them is `regular file`.

Comment: I see, but my question was what is the difference between the two functions and if they are usable in MFC. I did a little testing on my own and they seem to both return the same true/false values on the files I tested them on which is what led me to my question :P

Comment: [The Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem-enumerations?view=msvc-170#file_type) detail what a "regular file" would be.  In Windows, `is_regular_file()` seems to indicate that the path both `exists()` and _isn't a directory_.

Comment: so (1) it exists and (2) it is a file, not a folder; specifically, does a zip file count as a file or a folder, since I will also be zipping files; does this mean exists just checks if the file / folder exists, it does not care that it is a directory ? directory and folder are interchangeable words correct ?

Comment: I see no reason that you cannot use `filesystem` with `MFC`. Does the `MFC` mechanism have facilities for detecting symlinks?

Comment: yes, from my understanding it does

Comment: although i do not exactly know what that means :')

Comment: In most cases, I'd suggest that both `is_regular_file` and `exists` are probably sub-optimal. You're going to need to read the file to be able to zip it, so I'd use `access` to see whether it's readable. Better still, avoid race conditions by just trying to zip the file, and see whether that works or not. For a robust program, you need to handle the case that it doesn't work anyway (e.g., when you checked, it was a readable file, but while you were zipping other files, the user deleted one you'd previously verified).

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: use [std::filesystem::is_regular_file()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_regular_file), [std::filesystem::is_symlink()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_symlink) and [std::filesystem::is_directory()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory).

---

There are several [file types defined in std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_type):

```
Constant    Meaning
none        indicates that the file status has not been evaluated yet, or an error occurred when evaluating it
not_found   indicates that the file was not found (this is not considered an error)
regular     a regular file
directory   a directory
symlink     a symbolic link
block       a block special file
character   a character special file
fifo        a FIFO (also known as pipe) file
socket      a socket file
implementation-defined  an additional implementation-defined constant for each additional file type supported by the implementation (e.g. MSVC STL defines junction for NTFS junctions)
unknown     the file exists but its type could not be determined
```

So in first glance, [std::filesystem::exists()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists) would be what you want.

But you're adding files to a ZIP archive, and AFAICT, ZIP only supports regular files, symlinks, and directories, so that's what you should use.

You wouldn't archive sockets or NTFS junctions even if they existed and were given in command line.

---

To clarify:

A "regular file" is a file that has data that is (a) stored by the filesystem and (b) has no semantics assigned to it by the filesystem - i.e. the filesystem doesn't know how to read the file or act on it.

For example, a MS Word document is something that MS Word understand, but the filesystem only knows that it's a bunch of bytes.
A symlink, on the other hand, is something the filesystem stores, and knows how to act on (follow the link).
A block special file is something that is not actually stored by the filesystem, but rather just a piece of metadata that other parts of the OS act on.
A ZIP archive, or RAR, are files that the filesystem stores. But it doesn't know how to read them or act on them, so they are regular files.
In the old Windows Explorer, the "shortcuts" on your desktop were small files stored by the filesystem, but it was Explorer that knew how to read them - they weren't symbolic links, they were regular files. (Maybe that's still the case, I haven't checked recently.)

Comment: Windows shortcuts and Linux symbolic links are both small files. The difference is at which level the interpretation happens. Symbolic links are **not** interpreted by the file system, but they are interpreted by the kernel. This is why they can cross different filesystems. Hard links are interpreted by the filesystem and cannot cross filesystems. Windows shortcuts are not interpreted by the kernel, that's done in the Shell.

Comment: True, but this distinction would add more confusion than clarity to the explanation.

Comment: thank you  the clarifications at the bottom helped a lot too !! two quick follow ups - (1) this will allow me to add zip files to the zip file using "is_regular_file" (from what I understand in the the 2nd to last paragraph "a ziparchive .." (2)how does the system and filesystem deal with an```unknown```file type

Comment: (1) Just try it... (the answer yes). (2) This probably warrants its own SO question. Generally it doesn't, and you should skip it. Like block device, it just keeps the metadata, but unlike block device, nobody is going to act on it.